# After and Before Clauses

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-tense, descriptive-grammar

guys. I would like to ask whether a clause should always be in the past if it follows another clause starting with *after* in the past. For instance: After she read the note, she **understands/understood** the situation. 
Should we use **understood** here even if the person still understands it?

Another question
Is it possible to use a clause in the present before a *before*-clause in the present to indicate that the person has started to do it and still does it. For instance: He **loves** me before he sees me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to describe the current situation, I would use *since* rather than *after.*

Since reading the note, she now understands the situation.

With *before,* it needs to be:

He loves me before having seen me, *or*

He loves me before he has seen me.

Comment: Do we have to use the present perfect when it comes to this *before*? I have seen many times the present is used after this *before*.

Comment: If you are simply describing a list of actions, yes. _He cleans his teeth before he goes to bed_. In your example sentence, _before he sees me_ seems to mean _even though he has not yet seen me_.

Comment: I see. So, if it refers to one particular situation which is neither a schedule nor a habit, I should use the present perfect, right? What if it's in the past? Should I use the past perfect or simply use the past?

Comment: _He loved me before having seen me_ or _before he had (even) seen me_.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, Kate :)

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again. There is still a little confusion regarding this matter. In your answer, you wrote *since reading the note, she now **understands** the situation*. So, it is possible to use a *since* clause with a clause in the present? Shouldn't we always use it with a clause in the present perfect/present perfect continuous?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with verbs like _know, understand, think_ etc.

Comment: great. Thanks a lot.